# Building multiple dynamic tables with ng-repeat in angularjs using template

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to achieve the following in angualrjs:

I have multiple information lines, that each can be clicked regardless of the others.
When I click on a line, a div is opened and a table is shown in regarding that line.

My html now looks like this:

```
<div ng-app="TModule" ng-cloak>
<div class="myDiv" ng-controller="tController as tCtrl">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="option in tCtrl.availableOptions" ng-click="tCtrl.toggleOpen(option.id)">
            <div>
                <h2>{{option.name}}</h2>
                <div ng-show="isOpen(option.id)">
                  //Table should go here
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

My table template is the same for all lines and should look like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
       <th>Header I</th>
        ...
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat...>...</tr>
    ....
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to happen with clicking on any li item, that it will call a function on the controller which will make an ajax call, and fill the table using a template, with the results receive.

My problem is that I don't know how to fill each table with the same template and to have different information (without using array that will store each information)

Not sure if it is possible in angular and what will be the best way to achieve this?

Each line can be opened together and each line has a different set of information.

Comment: It can be done. I had to do this about 2 years ago for our current site and set up a table with expanding rows. The expanded rows also held tables with dynamic content that was unique to the row. I created a directive that inserted the row based on the requesting element id. The template for the table was in the directive and was compiled on the inserted tr after I got the required data from our API. It is a bit of work getting everything set up but it certainly can be done.

Comment: I've thought about going in the 'directive' direction, at the moment it seems the best solution, thx. Anyone else has idea?